# node js express debug

Tags: node.js, debugging, express

I have a few issues while debugging node js express app.
first issue is that the Debugger listening on a different port. That is fine but the debugger won't stop on any of the breakpoints, and all I see on the page are some header prints:

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 4.6.85.31
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v5.3.0
Content-Length: 0
```

Any advise?

Comment: Are you using the cluster module ?